# loading select with database values using jquery and ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using jquery to add a div for select option.

```
var div_secretary = div_secretary + '<div>Secretary:';
var div_secretary = div_secretary + '<select style="margin-left:5px;" id="select_reviewer_secretary" >';
var div_secretary = div_secretary + '<option>-select-</option>';
var div_secretary = div_secretary + '</select></div>
```

my jquery function for getting database values is

```
$(function() {
    var items = "";
    $.getJSON("GetSecretaries.php", function(data) {

        $.each(data, function(index, item) {
            items += "<option value='" + item.CODE + "'>" + item.SUBCODE + "</option>";
        });
        $("#select_reviewer_secretary").html(items);
    });
});
```

my php code for getting database is

```
$tac_Secretaries = array();

while ($result = oci_fetch_assoc($parse_Reviewer_test)) {
    $tac_Secretaries[] = $result;
}

echo json_encode(array('value' => $tac_Secretaries));
```

when i loads the page i getting the json values like

```
{"value":[{"CODE":"3621","SUBCODE":"4"},{"CODE":"1561","SUBCODE":"1"}]}
```

here how i can load these values into select options .
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either change PHP code or jQuery Code,

I am suggesting to change PHP Code, change last line to:

```
echo json_encode($tac_Secretaries);
```

Comment: but how to load this value into options

Comment: You are using it right in `getJSON`. Just use, `item.CODE` & `item.SUBCODE`

Comment: i am getting db values.but it cant load into the options.

Comment: post the response from DB here

Comment: [{"CODE":"3621","SUBCODE":"4"},{"CODE":"1561","SUBCODE":"1"}]

Comment: `select` tag should be available on page. I tried using `items='';
$.each([{"CODE":"3621","SUBCODE":"4"},{"CODE":"1561","SUBCODE":"1"}] , function(index, item) {
            items += "<option value='" + item.CODE + "'>" + item.SUBCODE + "</option>";
        });` & it is working fine.

Comment: problem solved.i used ajax call on an event instead of page onload.